# How to bind an ObservableCollection to a TreeView in a hierarchical way?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, observablecollection

I know this may be a duplicate but no solution works for me. So I have a class `Technik` which has these properties:

```
public class Technik
{
    public bool checkedTe { get; set; }

    public int TechnikID { get; set; }

    public string anlagengruppe { get; set; }

    public string techniktyp { get; set; }

    public string anlage { get; set; }

    public string bemerkung { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a `DataTable` with 216 rows and each row is getting into a `Technik` object that is added into my `ObservableCollection<Technik>` like:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtTechnik.Rows)
{
     Technik technik = new Technik();

     technik.checkedTe = (bool)dr.ItemArray[0];
     technik.TechnikID = (int)dr.ItemArray[1];
     technik.anlagengruppe = (string)dr.ItemArray[2];
     technik.techniktyp = (string)dr.ItemArray[3];
     technik.anlage = (string)dr.ItemArray[4];
     technik.bemerkung = (string)dr.ItemArray[5];

     TechnikCollection.Add(technik);
}
```

I want to bind my `ObservableCollection` like:

```
* anlagengruppe
    * techniktyp
          *anlage
             * TechnikID
```

Right now I'm getting nowhere, so maybe you guys out there can help me.
Actual my tree view looks like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="850" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="464" 
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding TechnicTable}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding TechnicTable}">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=anlagengruppe}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding techniktyp}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**Edit:**
Maybe some of you think that my tree view `ItemsSource` is not the correct collection, this is the right one, there is some more code where I change collections.

Comment: Your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` doesn't correspond the `Technik` model: there is no `TechnicTable` collection in that class but you're trying to bind to that property.

Comment: At first thanks for the EDIT... My problem is that I dont know how to bind correctly those properties of the Technik Model... this was all just try and error and see what I get... So maybe you can show me how to bind correctly those properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am skeptical of this design. Why do you feel it's useful and helpful to the user to present a single object and its property values as if that object had some hierarchical structure to it?

If all you're trying to do is impose some *visual* structure on the user interface, that's easily done without using `TreeView`. For example:

```
class TableItem
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    public TableItem() { }

    public TableItem(string property1, string property2, string property3)
    {
        Property1 = property1;
        Property2 = property2;
        Property3 = property3;
    }
}

class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TableItem> TableItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TableItem>();
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO46300831HiearchicalObservable.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO46300831HiearchicalObservable"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel>
      <l:ViewModel.TableItems>
        <l:TableItem Property1="Item #1, property #1"
                     Property2="Item #1, property #2"
                     Property3="Item #1, property #3"/>
        <l:TableItem Property1="Item #2, property #1"
                     Property2="Item #2, property #2"
                     Property3="Item #2, property #3"/>
        <l:TableItem Property1="Item #3, property #1"
                     Property2="Item #3, property #2"
                     Property3="Item #3, property #3"/>
      </l:ViewModel.TableItems>
    </l:ViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:TableItem}">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TableItems}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

That said, if you *must* use `TreeView` and you want for the view to update as the collection is modified, it seems to me you can accomplish that by using an intermediate collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (easily done simply by inheriting `ObservableCollection<T>` and tracking the original collection. The intermediate collection is needed, so that items can be converted from the original single-object item to a hierarchical item type that can be used with the `TreeView` class. For example:

```
class HierarchicalTableItem
{
    public string Text { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<HierarchicalTableItem> Items { get; }

    public HierarchicalTableItem(string text, HierarchicalTableItem child = null)
    {
        Text = text;
        Items = child != null ? new[] { child } : null;
    }
}

class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand AddCommand { get; }
    public ICommand InsertCommand { get; }
    public ICommand RemoveCommand { get; }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TableItem> TableItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TableItem>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => TableItems.Add(_CreateTableItem()));
        InsertCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => TableItems.Insert(Index, _CreateTableItem()));
        RemoveCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => TableItems.RemoveAt(Index));
    }

    private int _itemNumber;

    private TableItem _CreateTableItem()
    {
        _itemNumber = (_itemNumber < TableItems.Count ? TableItems.Count : _itemNumber) + 1;

        return new TableItem(
            $"Item #{_itemNumber}, property #1",
            $"Item #{_itemNumber}, property #2",
            $"Item #{_itemNumber}, property #3");
    }
}

class ConvertingObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<object>
{
    private readonly IValueConverter _converter;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<T> _collection;

    public ConvertingObservableCollection(IValueConverter converter, ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        _converter = converter;
        _collection = collection;
        _ResetItems();
        _collection.CollectionChanged += _OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void _OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                _AddItems(e);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                _RemoveItems(e);
                _AddItems(e);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                _RemoveItems(e);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                _ReplaceItems(e);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                _ResetItems();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void _ReplaceItems(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
        {
            this[i] = _Convert(e.NewItems[i]);
        }
    }

    private void _AddItems(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
        {
            Insert(i + e.NewStartingIndex, _Convert(e.NewItems[i]));
        }
    }

    private void _RemoveItems(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = e.OldItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            RemoveAt(i + e.OldStartingIndex);
        }
    }

    private void _ResetItems()
    {
        Clear();
        foreach (T t in _collection)
        {
            Add(_Convert(t));
        }
    }

    private object _Convert(object value)
    {
        return _converter.Convert(value, typeof(T), null, null);
    }
}

class TableItemHierarchicalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TableItem tableItem = value as TableItem;

        if (tableItem == null)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        return new HierarchicalTableItem(tableItem.Property1,
                    new HierarchicalTableItem(tableItem.Property2,
                        new HierarchicalTableItem(tableItem.Property3)));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class ConvertingCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IValueConverter converter = parameter as IValueConverter;

        if (converter == null || value == null ||
            value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        Type resultType = typeof(ConvertingObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(value.GetType().GenericTypeArguments);

        return Activator.CreateInstance(resultType, converter, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO46300831HiearchicalObservable.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO46300831HiearchicalObservable"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel>
      <l:ViewModel.TableItems>
        <l:TableItem Property1="Item #1, property #1"
                     Property2="Item #1, property #2"
                     Property3="Item #1, property #3"/>
        <l:TableItem Property1="Item #2, property #1"
                     Property2="Item #2, property #2"
                     Property3="Item #2, property #3"/>
        <l:TableItem Property1="Item #3, property #1"
                     Property2="Item #3, property #2"
                     Property3="Item #3, property #3"/>
      </l:ViewModel.TableItems>
    </l:ViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <l:ConvertingCollectionConverter x:Key="convertingCollectionConverter1"/>
    <l:TableItemHierarchicalConverter x:Key="tableItemConverter1"/>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
      <UniformGrid Columns="4">
        <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Insert" Command="{Binding InsertCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Index}"/>
      </UniformGrid>
      <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TableItems,
              Converter={StaticResource convertingCollectionConverter1},
              ConverterParameter={StaticResource tableItemConverter1}}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

This alternative relies on three key classes:

- `ConvertingObservableCollection<T>` — This does the work of watching the original collection and presenting converted items according to the current state of that original collection.
- `ConvertingCollectionConverter` — This converts the original collection to the `ConvertingObservableCollection<T>` object for the purpose of binding to the `TreeView`.
- `TableItemHierarchicalConverter` — This converts the individual original item objects into a hierarchy of objects suitable for display in the `TreeView`.

Of course, there is also the simple container class `HierarchicalTableItem` which is used to represent the hierarchy for each table item.

Ultimately, the key to remember is that for a `TreeView`, you *must* be presenting items that have a recursive nature, such that a single `HierarchicalDataTemplate` element can be used to define how to present *each level* of the tree. This means that a single data item must have some property that can be used for the `ItemsSource` of the template, which is itself some type of collection of the same type of data item.

Comment: Thanks for your responsive! Yesterday I noticed myself that my Data Model is crap so I extended it - and now I can do the hierarchical way.Thank you for your time and explanation!