# TreeView with nested ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a `ListOfApps<(App>)` including some properties like Name, Version, CurrentUser or CurrentOwner (both including ObservableCollections) and want to display them in a TreeView. These are the interfaces for a better explanation:

```
public interface IApp
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Version { get; }
    User CurrentUser { get; }
    Owner CurrentOwner { get; }
}

public interface IUser
{
    // A property of Info is e.g. Description
    ObservableCollection<Info> ListOfInfos { get; }
}

public interface IOwner
{
    // A property of Member is e.g. Name
    ObservableCollection<Member> ListOfMembers { get; }
}
```

The result of the Treeview should look like this:

```
- App1                      Name (String)
-- Version                  Version (String)
-- CurrentUser              App.CurrentUser (User) -> Name (String)
---  Info1                  App.CurrentUser.ListOfInfos (ObservableCollection<Info>) -> Description (String)
---  Info2                  App.CurrentUser.ListOfInfos (ObservableCollection<Info>) -> Description (String)
---  Info3                  App.CurrentUser.ListOfInfos (ObservableCollection<Info>) -> Description (String)
-- CurrentOwner             App.CurrentOwner (Owner) -> Name (String)
---  Member1                App.CurrentOwner.ListOfMembers (ObservableCollection<Member>) -> Name (String)
---  Member2                App.CurrentOwner.ListOfMembers (ObservableCollection<Member>) -> Name (String)

- App2                      Name (String)
-- Version                  Version (String)
-- CurrentUser              App.CurrentUser (User) -> Name (String)
---  Info1                  App.CurrentUser.ListOfInfos (ObservableCollection<Info>) -> Description (String)
---  Info2                  App.CurrentUser.ListOfInfos (ObservableCollection<Info>) -> Description (String)
-- CurrentOwner             App.CurrentOwner (Owner) -> Name (String)
---  Member1                App.CurrentOwner.ListOfMembers (ObservableCollection<Member>) -> Name (String)
---  Member2                App.CurrentOwner.ListOfMembers (ObservableCollection<Member>) -> Name (String)
---  Member3                App.CurrentOwner.ListOfMembers (ObservableCollection<Member>) -> Name (String)

- App3
- ...
```

I've tried to realize it by some HierarchicalDataTemplate, but without any success. This is my approach:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfApps}">

    <TreeView.Resources>

        <!-- App Items -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type appConfig:App}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- App Item: Version -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type appConfig:App}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Version}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- CurrentUser -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type appConfig:User}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfInfos}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentUser.Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type appConfig:Info}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- CurrentOwner -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type appConfig:Owner}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMembers}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentOwner.Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type appConfig:Member}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: To use `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, there needs to be a _single_ property of the top-level data item that represents the children. So, e.g. your `IApp` object has to have a collection as a property in which the `Version`, `CurrentUser`, and `CurrentOwner` properties are all contained as individual elements in that collection. Your question is really too broad, but as it happened I recently answered a similarly broad question (in spite of it being too broad) and you might find the technique there useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46310411

Comment: Bottom line: you either need to change your data structure itself, or you need to provide an implementation similar to what I show in that answer, in which you convert your flat data structure to one that `TreeView` can work with. IMHO, you may want to reconsider the use of `TreeView` here, and instead opt for including collapsible elements in a single data template for your `IApp` object, via the [`Expander`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

Comment: Thank you. The expander hint is very good.